# Usability of "agenda" view vs "basic" view for calendar?

Tags: calendar

For web-application time slots scheduling (**slots are of 1-2 different durations 15 minutes-1 hour mostly, not arbitrary, no overlaps**), basic CRUD, no drag-n-drop rescheduling, there **maybe lots of 20-minute slots during the day**, but information is limited to short title, which of the two approaches is better (for week view)?

Basic week view, best illustrated by FullCalendar example, that is, no time-line, height does not reflect duration, imagine past events greyed-out:

https://fullcalendar.io/views/basicWeek/

[image]

(event addition - just click on a day)

Or more google-calendar like so-called agenda view:

https://fullcalendar.io/views/agendaWeek/

[image]

(event addition - drag-n-release like in google)

This is year 2017, and I noticed, users are more comfortable with google-like option (is it even true?), but it's not general-purpose calendar in question, so is there still place for simpler calendar view or should we leave that behind? Are there any other UX drawbacks in basic calendar except for users' familiarity with google-like calendars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's important to understand the **purpose** of each view.

- **The basic calendar view** - This is used to show all the events of the day (or each day of the week). The idea here is to inform the user the events lined up for the day.

  - *When to use it?* - This is like a grocery list. You list out the things you need to get. So use it to list out the events for the upcoming days.
- **The agenda view** - This is used to help the user **plan** their day. Each event is shown in a timeline so that you can quickly see the overlaps, the free slots and the event line-up.

  - *When to use it?* - This is like a To-do list. You usually list out the tasks in the order of priority or by time. Use it to plan events for the upcoming days (like meetings)

Hope this answers your question

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense, however, the usage is not black and white. It's a bit of both: First, planning time slots, then observe the situation, and plan more.

Comment: True. Usually calendars have both views available to make things flexible. Agenda mostly comes in with Week and Day view. You could have both in your case